# CollectionViewの非同期処理

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

1.NCMBから画像のurlを取得し、
2.配列に加えた後
3.URLにアクセスして画像を取得
4.CollectionViewのCellの上に載っているImageViewに表示する

という作業をしたいのですが、データストアからデータを取得するより先に戻り値を返してしまい、処理が終了してしまいます。

4の処理を遅延させて、データストアからデータを取得し配列に加えた後に、CollectionViewのCellの上に載っているImageViewに表示するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    // クラスのNCMBObjectを作成
    let obj = NCMBObject(className: "image")
    // objectIdプロパティを設定
    obj?.objectId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    // 設定されたobjectIdを元にデータストアからデータを取得
    obj?.fetchInBackground { error in
        if error != nil {
            // 取得に失敗した場合の処理
        }else{
            // 取得に成功した場合の処理
            // (例)取得したデータの出力
            print(obj!.object(forKey: "imageUrl"))
            self.imageUrlArray.append(obj!.object(forKey: "imageUrl") as! String)

        }
    }

    // Cell はストーリーボードで設定したセルのID
    let testCell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    var url = URL(string: self.imageUrlArray[indexPath.row])

    do {
        self.imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url!,options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe);

    } catch {
        print("Error: can't create image.")
    }

    // Tag番号を使ってImageViewのインスタンス生成
    let imageView = testCell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    // 画像配列の番号で指定された要素の名前の画像をUIImageとする
    imageView.image = UIImage(data: self.imageData! as Data)

    return testCell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

簡単に言うと、簡単ではありません…。

- 非同期処理をうまく使うコツは「完了を待つ」のではなく、「完了してから実行されるところで結果を使う」ように頭を切り替えることです。

あなたのご質問の文面から言うと、「4の処理を遅延させ」るのではなく、「3.URLにアクセスして画像を取得」が「完了してから実行されるところで結果(その画像)を使う」と言うことになります。

つまり頭を切り替えて、取得した画像は完了ハンドラー(あなたのコードの`{ error in ... }`)の中で使えば良いと言うことになります。

もちろん`collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`の結果は画像取得が完了するまで返さないなんてことはできませんから、仮の画像を入れたCellをすぐに返すと言う必要があります。

- Cellは再利用されるのでその考慮も必要です

`UITableViewCell`や`UICollectionViewCell`のインスタンスは出来るだけ再利用するように動きますので、画像の取得が完了した時には、その画像を設定したかったCellはもう再利用されて別の用途に使われているかもしれません。

(たまに`UITableView`を使った画面を高速にスクロールすると、本来とは違う画像が表示されるアプリがあったりしますが、この辺の考慮が足りない実装になっている可能性が高いと思われます。)

何らかの方法で、画像を設定したかったCellが再利用されていないことを確認しないといけません。

---

以上のような内容を踏まえてあなたのコードを書き直すと、次のような感じになります。NCMBを簡単に試すことはできないので、コンパイルが通る、程度のチェックしかしていませんから、このような流れになる、という雰囲気を理解するためのものと思ってください。

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // Cell はストーリーボードで設定したセルのID
    let testCell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    // Tag番号を使ってImageViewのインスタンス取得 <- ここで「生成」するのではない
    let imageView = testCell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    // クラスのNCMBObjectを作成⇒guard letを使えば後の`?`や`!`が不要になる
    guard let obj = NCMBObject(className: "image") else {
        //NCMBが利用できない場合の画像もアプリ内に用意する
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Unavailable")
        //たとえ何かの異常があってもnon-nilのUICollectionViewCellを返さないとコンパイルできない
        return testCell
    }
    //Loading用の仮イメージをアプリ内に用意して、ロード中はそちらを表示させる
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Loading")
    // objectIdプロパティを設定
    obj.objectId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    //画像ローディングの管理IDを作成する(ユニークな値であれば何でも良い、arc4random()は実用的に十分)
    let loadingId = Int(Int32(bitPattern: arc4random())) //<-32 bit環境でも動くようにIntに変換している
    //管理IDをCellにも設定、tagは他用途に使う可能性もあるのでできれば専用カスタムCellにloadingId属性を持たせた方が良い
    testCell.tag = loadingId
    // 設定されたobjectIdを元にデータストアからデータを取得
    obj.fetchInBackground { error in
        if let error = error {
            // 取得に失敗した場合の処理
            print(error)
        } else {
            // 取得に成功した場合の処理
            // (例)取得したデータの出力
            let imageUrlString = obj.object(forKey: "imageUrl") as! String
            print(imageUrlString)
            //Cellは再利用されるので、load完了した時にはもう別用途に使われているかもしれないからそのチェック
            guard testCell.tag == loadingId else {
                print("Cell seems to be reused")
                return
            }
            //外部から取得した文字列はURLとして不正かもしれないので、それもチェックしておく
            guard let url = URL(string: imageUrlString) else {
                print("Invalid imageUrl")
                return
            }
            //イメージデータのロードも完了ハンドラーの中でやってしまう(mappedIfSafeは外部URLからのloadには使用しない)
            let imageData: Data
            do {
                imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            } catch {
                print("Error: can't create image.")
                return
            }
            //取得したデータをUIImageに変換、これも失敗する可能性があるのでguard-letでチェック
            guard let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
                print("Invalid imageData")
                return
            }
            //ここまで無事に終了したら目的のセルに画像を設定する
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                imageView.image = image
                //Swiftの配列はスレッドセーフではないので配列の更新は必ずメインスレッドで行うことにした方が安全
                if self.imageUrlArray.count <= indexPath.row {
                    self.imageUrlArray.append(contentsOf: (self.imageUrlArray.count...indexPath.row).map{_ in ""})
                }
                //非同期処理は順不同で終了するので、結果を配列の最後に入れても正しい順序にはならない
                self.imageUrlArray[indexPath.row] = imageUrlString
            }
        }
    }
    //Loadが完了したら画像を設定するよ、という準備が済んだら(Loading画像の設定された)Cellを返す
    return testCell
}
```

細かい部分あれこれ手直しが必要かもしれませんが、あなた自身の環境と目的に合わせて修正しながらお試しください。

画像の遅延ロードをサポートするようなサードパーティ製のライブラリもあるようです(残念ながら私は使ったことがないので詳しくはわかりません)ので、そう言ったものを調べてみるのも良いかもしれません。

Comment: 動作確認しました。
ところでcellの要素数を、あらかじめ宣言した配列の要素数ではなくNCMBのオブジェクト数に応じて決めるには、やはり非同期処理が必要になるのでしょうか？

imageUrlArrayの要素数だけcellをつくる以下のコードの動作が始まるまえにNCMBのオブジェクト数を取得したい場合、imageUrlArrayの宣言はどのタイミングで行えばよいのでしょうか。

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // 要素数を入れる、要素以上の数字を入れると表示でエラーとなる
        return imageUrlArray.count;
    }`

Comment: @sashihara さん、細部ではいろいろな考え方ができる(ローディング画像のみのセルを決め打ちで幾つか用意するか、完全にゼロから始めて一つずつ増やしていくか等)でしょうが、最終的なセルの数自体は、通信が終わるまでわからないわけですから、何らかの形で非同期処理は必要になると言うことになります。ユーザビリティー的には劣るかもしれませんが、画像も含めた1セル分の全データが取得できた時点でそのセルを増やす、とした方が、コードはシンプルになるかもしれません。コメント中のコード例ですが、`imageUrlArray`(と言うよりも画像以外のデータも入れて`cellInfoArray`とかにした方が良いかもしれません)は最初っから要素ゼロの状態で宣言しておけば良いでしょう。いろいろ試してみて、わからない部分が残れば、また別スレを立てて質問してください。